# How can I recreate a request in python since I have only it's log?

Tags: python, json, object, python-requests, request

I'm writing a Python script to load a collection of logs from API requests. I need to reissue these requests in debug mode to fetch additional information that is not available in the original logs because they were not made in debug mode. The logs are stored in JSON format, and the request body of each log is scattered throughout the JSON structure. Here's an example:

```
    "request_body.additional_information.sales_channel": "my sales channel",
    "request_body.additional_information.platform": "my_sales_platform",
    "request_body.additional_information.lead_time_business_days": 1,
    "request_body.additional_information.rule_tags": ["my_first_tag", "my_second_tag"],
    "request_body.destination_zip_code": 22222222,
    "request_body.origin_zip_code": 11111111,
    "request_body.products": null,
    "request_body.shipment_sub_type": null
```

How can I reconstruct the request body object to represent its content as it was in the original request? Here's an example of what I'm aiming for:

```
request_body: {
    "origin_zip_code": "11111111",
    "destination_zip_code": "22222222",
    "additional_information": {
    "lead_time_business_days": 1,
    "platform": "my_sales_platform",
    "sales_channel": "my_sales_channel"
    "rule_tags": ["my_first_tag", "my_second_tag"]
    },
    "products": null,
    "shipment_sub_type": null
}
```

Is there a library that I can use for this task?

I have solved this problem using the following approach:

```
requestBody = {
    'origin_zip_code': str(payload['request_body.origin_zip_code']),
    'destination_zip_code': str(payload['request_body.destination_zip_code']),
    'products': str(payload['request_body.products'])
}
```

For each log, I recreate the request body by including only the necessary information specific to its endpoint. However, since the API has multiple endpoints and the content of the request body varies depending on the endpoint, this approach may not work for all scenarios. That's why I am attempting to reconstruct the request body.